# Service to be stopped in batch

Tags: windows, batch-file, windows-services, scheduled-tasks

I would like to check if a service is running. If it is I would like it to be stopped. I do have alot of services so I want it to be run in a Array or someting.

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "MyServiceName" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
  if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
  REM Put your code you want to execute here
  REM For example, the following line
  net stop"MyServiceName"
)
```

Then I have for example service1, service2, service3 and service4

How can this be addes wihout needing to write this for loop four times?

Comment: Always just run a `net stop xxx`? there are no side effects if xxx is not running.

Answer (score 0):

```
for %%S in ("service1" "service2" "service3") do (
  for /F "tokens=3 delims=: " %%H in ('sc query "%%~S" ^| findstr "        STATE"') do (
   if /I "%%H" NEQ "RUNNING" (
   REM Put your code you want to execute here
   REM For example, the following line
   net stop"%%~S"
  )

)
```

?